# IE text wrapping issues

Tags: html, css, squarespace

On [jensglobaltravel.com](https://www.jensglobaltravel.com/) front page under "Upcoming Featured Trips". When Internet Explorer is zoomed in 125% or higher. The title text within a paragraph tag is not wrapping instead it is clipped off. The website is built using the website builder Square space. We have tried,

- text-overflow
- overflow
- things having to do with width and flex

Everything we have tried does not work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `white-space: nowrap` on the `image-slide-title` div. Removing that seems to fix the issue.

Alternatively, you can try adding `white-space: normal` to the paragraph element. This should reset the white-space attribute without affecting the `image-slide-title` class itself, assuming you plan on using that class elsewhere on the site.